# can you find an algorithm for this function?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, halting-problem

consider the following function
$$
\begin{align*}
f(m,n) &=
   \begin{cases}
      k & \text{if program $m$ halts on input $n$ after $k$ steps} \\
      m & \text{if program $m$ loops on input $n$} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
can you find an algorithm for this function?

Comment: We expect you to make your question useful for others by providing context, motivation, and background; and by doing research and trying to solve your problem yourself before asking and showing your research and what progress you have made.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.  Given the number of questions you have already asked about the halting problem, I would have expected that you would have some idea about what computability theory would have to say about the possibility of computing this function.

Comment: Yes, by invoking the halting problem. This is trivial. But you did not answer: what is unclear ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust non-computability of halting problem is unclear to me, I need to expand my understanding of algorithms to decide whether it's computable or not

Comment: Decidability is stronger than computability.

Comment: @raoof, Comments are not intended for asking new questions, requesting extended interaction or discussion, and so forth.  Instead, comments are intended to help you improve the question - which involves [edit]ing your question based on the feedback you've received.

Comment: @D.W. do you think I should post a new question? this question has -3 votes and already has an answer

Comment: @raoof, If you have a new question, the appropriate way to ask it is to ask a new question, not to post a comment.  I encourage you to follow the feedback and advice you've already received on this question and past questions when formulating a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The halting problem is a very well known undecidable problem. Suppose your function $f$ is computable. Then the following algorithm can solve the halting problem:

```
Input: code m and input n
Output: true if program m halts on input n, false otherwise

Let k = f(m, n)
if k ≠ m:
   return true
else:
   simulate k steps of program m on input n
   if it halts before k steps, return true, otherwise return false
```

We conclude by reduction that your function is not computable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141183/discussion-on-answer-by-nathaniel-can-you-find-an-algorithm-for-this-function).